# sssd prevent particular backend servers

Tags: active-directory, centos7, dnsmasq, sssd

Just came across an interesting problem using `sssd` where I was able to `getent someuser@example.com` but `getent group somegroup@example.com` was failing. Ended up finding out with `adcli info example.com` that there were two DC's in the forest that were not reachable and causing the issue.

I now have it working by restricting which AD machines are used by using `ad_server` and `ad_backup_server`. I've spent the last few hours reading manuals, blogs, etc. but I'm wondering would there be a way to do the opposite?... So, instead of having an allow list using `ad_server`, having some kind of blacklist? I haven't discovered any options like that. Although it may be my lack of knowledge/in-depth experience using `sssd`, `realmd`. I'm open to solutions outside of using some form of `sssd` config options. I'm using `dnsmasq` on the server as well, so if there are any solutions that would work using that, I'm open to anything.

Answer (score 1):

No, I'm sorry, this is not possible. Only whitelisting is.

Comment: It does answer the question, but details about why it's not possible would make the answer more convincing and useful.

Comment: It's just not implemented.